# Return MySQLi object from function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following function declared in a global.php file:

```
function dbconnect(){
   $mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpasswd,$dbdatabase);
   if ($mysqli->connect_error){
      echo ($mysqli->connect_error);
      return null;
   } else {
      return $mysqli;
   }
}
```

I have made 100% certain the the $dbdatabase is a valid database. I call the function I get a valid object back without errors; however when I attempt to execute a query, the object reports that no database is selected.  If I remove the code and execute it directly where I need it - no issues.  Am I missing something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The values `$dbserver` `$dbuser` `$dbpasswd` and `$dbdatabase` are not defined in the scope of the function.

You should pass them through as parameters such as:

```
function dbconnect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbdatabase){
```

Or you could use the poor coding method way and globalize the variables by doing such:

```
function dbconnect(){
    global $dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbdatabase;
```

I would suggest using the first method, or just define the variables within the function.

Comment: OMG!  I cannot believe I made such a rookie mistake.  Thanks Marcus!  Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

actually there is an another way too. You just don't need to make all of them global. instead of that you can make them locally.

like...

function dbConnect(){

```
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

 $con = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$dbname);
 return $con ;
```

}